# Why does the SAPUI5 getBindingContext("modelName") sometimes returns undefined?

Tags: sapui5

I have an  UI5 component that loads 5 items automatically:

```
<m:Table  id="idOverviewPage" 
          backgroundDesign="Translucent"
          items="{path: 'theModel>/TheODataServiceThatGetsItems', 
                  parameters : { $count : true }, 
                  sorter: { path: 'ProcessedDate', descending: true }}" 
          growing="true"
          growingScrollToLoad="true" 
          growingThreshold="5"
          width="auto">
```

The items in the table are represented with the <m:ColumnListItem > objects. The first 5 ColumnListItems get automatically obtained when the "TheODataServiceThatGetsItems" OData service from the above definition gets called as the page loads.

When the item is clicked on the following code runs:

```
var bindingContext = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("theModel");
```

This works, but when I navigate back to the Table, the **next 5 records** get automatically loaded. When any of the **next 5 records** are clicked on the above code returns `undefined` and the method fails. The **first 5 records** continue to work and the above code returns an object

What could be the cause of this ?

Comment: How are you creating the ColumnListItems? Is the template part of the XML or are you creating them some other way

Comment: I've updated the question: the items are obtained through the call to the declared OData service that is in the definition of the m:Table